# Use Regex to populate new column with substring from another column in Python

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a df and I want to add a column to this that extracts the data I need from another column. The column I am extracting from contains strings so I am guessing I need to use a regex or Re for this.

A simplified example of my df:

```
Column A    Column B                                
1           I want (this text) only                    
2           I only want (this) text          
3           that appears (in) the parentheses
4           but not every line has
5           (parentheses) in it
```

so I want my df to then look something like this:

```
Column A    Column B                            Column C                           
1           I want (this text) only              this
2           I only want (this) text              this
3           that appears (in) the parentheses    in
4           but not every line has
5           (parentheses) in it                  parentheses
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want just the *first* word inside the parentheses, then use `str.extract` as follows:

```py
df["C"] = df["B"].str.extract(r'\((\S+)')
```

If you want the full contents of the parentheses, then use:

```py
df["C"] = df["B"].str.extract(r'\((.*?)\)')
```